# Mysql table field name

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table named school, but its there in two databases `D1` AND `D2`. **First 10 records are there in D1 database** and **the rest 10 records in Database D2**.
There is a field name `name` . How can i combine table `school` from 2 databases.

since in query I have a portion like

```
where institution.iname=school.name ,
```

here since school is fetched from 2 databases ,How can I achieve this. THanks

Comment: so you just want to display 20 records right ? just the name only? And i presume its in php???Lastly where are you storing the rows after you got them.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Query with a table from 2 databases](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17310706/query-with-a-table-from-2-databases)

Answer (score 1):

Check [this](http://nathan.rambeck.org/blog/2-joining-mysql-tables-across-multiple-databases) out. Great stuff. Good luck!

```
SELECT d1.* FROM database1.school d1 LEFT JOIN database2.school d2 ON d1.name=d2.name WHERE d2.name IS NOT NULL;
```

Comment: link only answers are not encouraged.