# Merge similar data from two tables into one table

Tags: php, mysql

this is an illustration of what I need to do..

TABLE 1

```
  `----------
    ID     VALUE

    123    A

    123    B

    123    C

    123    D

    123    E

    123    F

    ----------`
```

TABLE 2

```
----------
ID        VALUE    STATUS

123        A       POSTED

123        B       POSTED

123        C       CANCEL

----------
```

OUTPUT

```
----------
VALUE     ID

A         POSTED

B         POSTED

C         CANCEL

D

E

F

----------
```

When I search for the ID, everything that has the ID in TABLE 1 needs to be shown when it has a duplicate in table 2 information that does not exist in TABLE1 should merge to be shown in an OUTPUT TABLE... I can only search using the ID

can anyone give me a headstart on how to achieve this in php., mysql is the database ., Im new to this., thanks in advance.. :)

the tables are from two different databases..

Comment: Have a look at using `JOIN` in your queries. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/419375/sql-join-differences May help you understand the types that are avilable

Comment: To ALL: Thanks for the replies . Im gonna try them and research more.. thanks for the headstart :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select t1.id, t1.value,t2.status from table1 t1 
left join table2 t2 on 
t1.value = t2.value where t1.id = <urID>
```

[fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7fa2e/2)

If tables are on two database:

```
select t1.id, t1.value,t2.status from db1.table1 t1 
left join db2.table2 t2 on 
t1.value = t2.value where t1.id = <urID>
```

Comment: hi ., will this still work even when the tables are from two different databases.?

Comment: yes.. append database name with a '.' before table. eg db1.table1

Comment: but that would mean two databases are on same server

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11114197/join-tables-from-two-different-server .. this might help you to join tables in different servers

Comment: @Praveen what does t1 means..?

Comment: alias name for table1

Answer (score 0):

You need to connect the two table (your connection criteria is the id and value). So we join the tables on that criteria and select

```
select table1.id, table1.value, table2.status from table1 inner join table2 on (table1.id=table2.id AND table1.value=table2.value)
```

after the join in the Where clause you can specify your condition

like,

```
select table1.id, table1.value, table2.status from table1 inner join table2 on (table1.id=table2.id AND table1.value=table2.value) WHERE table.id = 123
```

Comment: HI., will this work even when the tables are from two different databases as well?

Comment: I don't think so. Two databases would mean two connections. I cannot guarantee that there is no way to query two databases in one query but I would suggest you to do two separate queries and combine data in PHP. I think that will be simpler option

Comment: a bit of research point here http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?52,526341,527014#msg-527014

Answer (score 0):

I think a simple `LEFT JOIN` is required

`SELECT TABLE_1.VALUE,TABLE_2.STATUS  FROM TABLE_1 LEFT JOIN  TABLE_2 ON  TABLE_1.ID =  TABLE_2.ID`

---

`SELECT D1.TABLE_1.VALUE, D2.TABLE_2.STATUS  FROM D1.TABLE_1 LEFT JOIN  D2.TABLE_2 ON  D1.TABLE_1.ID =  D2.TABLE_2.ID`

Comment: HI., will this work even when the tables are from two different databases as well?

Comment: I haven't used this but from these SO posts it seems possible [1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17310706/query-with-a-table-from-2-databases) , [2](http://bytes.com/topic/php/answers/721490-connecting-two-mysql-tables-different-databases)

Answer (score 0):

Try this pls

> Select * from table1 as tbl1 left join table2 as tbl2
>   on tbl1.id = tbl2.id and tbl1.value = tbl2.value